# Removing a file from a network share not in the recycle bin?

Tags: windows-server-2008, samba, share, windows

A client has removed an essential file by accident from a network share,
the file is not listed in the recycle bin on that system and not on the server either. Where did the file went?

Client: Windows 7 Enterprise
Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files deleted off network shares are permanently deleted. The warning dialog that pops up has a differently colored icon, and different text to indicate this fact.

If the server takes VSS snapshots you may be able to find the file by going to the directory that held the file, right click and bring up the Properties, then looking under the Previous Versions tab for the file.

Running a file recovery utility like [Glary Undelete](http://www.glarysoft.com/gun.html) on the server may recover the file.